# Bar chart output isn't what's expected

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am making a bar chart with D3. Most of the work is done, but the output is not behaving as I expect it to, and I can't figure the problem out.

The sample data is [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json), which is a JSON file comprising an array of figures for Gross Domestic Product in the US.

My bar chart is showing the curve I expect, although the figures start just over 2000, whereas in the data, they start at just over 200. I have attempted to change around the values but each time I tinker with the `y` positioning and height, I get unexpected results.

JS:

```
var fccDataUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json';
var dataset;
var fccData;

$.getJSON(fccDataUrl, (myData) => {

    dataset = myData.data;
    fccData = myData;
    console.log('dataset', dataset)
    console.log('fccData', fccData)

    var w = '800'
    var h = '500'
    var padding = 50;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', w)
                .attr('height', h)

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1947, 2015])
                    .range([padding, w - padding])

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])])
                    .range([h - padding, padding])

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .ticks(10)

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient('left')
                    .ticks(10)

    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .classed('bars', true)
        .attr('x', (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length) + 50)
        .attr('y', d => yScale(d[1]) - 50)
        .style('width', '4px')
        .style('height', d => h - yScale(d[1]))

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${h - padding})`)
        .call(xAxis)

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, 0)`)
        .call(yAxis)

});
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/zrjxmJ) of my work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mix-up between `h`, and the chart height. Here is an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVRpBr?editors=0010) with the `padding`, `h`, and `chartHeight` defined separately.

```
var fccDataUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json';
var dataset;
var fccData;

$.getJSON(fccDataUrl, (myData) => {

    dataset = myData.data;
    fccData = myData;
    console.log('dataset', dataset)
    console.log('fccData', fccData)

    var w = '800'
    var h = '500'
    var padding = {top: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50, left: 50};
    var chartWidth = w - padding.left - padding.right;
    var chartHeight = h - padding.top - padding.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)
        .append("g") // apply the transform to the parent elem instead of individually.
        .attr("transform", `translate(${padding.left}, ${padding.top})`)

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([1947, 2015])
        .range([0, chartWidth]) // no need to account for padding anymore

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])])
        .range([chartHeight, 0]) // no need to account for padding anymore

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(10)

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left')
        .ticks(10)

    svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .classed('bars', true)
    .attr('x', (d, i) => i * (w / dataset.length)) // no need to account for padding anymore
    .attr('y', d => yScale(d[1])) // no need to account for padding anymore
    .style('width', '4px')
    .style('height', d => chartHeight - yScale(d[1]))

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${chartHeight})`) // no need to account for padding anymore
    .call(xAxis)

    svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    //.attr('transform', `translate(${padding}, 0)`) // no need to account for padding anymore
    .call(yAxis)

});
```